# Comparing coefficients using mixed models in stata

Tags: stata, coefficients, mixed

I applied linear mixed models in Stata to have the annual rates of some variables in a some disease and compare different treatments during the follow up ( 3 time points).

`strPatId: subject as random effect`

I want to know individually for each treatment.
`keep if treatment == A mixed variableX c.time_visit || strPatId:time_visit , var reml keep if treatment == B mixed variableX c.time_visit || strPatId:time_visit , var reml`

annual rate treatment A = x /year (p<0.001)
annual rate treatment B = y /year (p<0.001)

I need to understand how I can compare the coefficients of annual rates between two treatments, i.e. to say that treatment A has _____ fold (p=___) faster than treatment B.

`mixed variableX c.time_visit##i.treatment || strPatId:time_visit , var reml`

May I assume that i.treatment#c.time_visit result is the difference of rates comparing both coefficients?